# Can StatsModels handle Pandas' nullable Int64 data type? If not, best workaround?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, nullable

(I think) I've discovered that the statsmodels module (or at least the part I'm using, see example below) cannot handle Pandas' nullable Int64 data type.
Below is a small (though I doubt minimal) working example.

This works fine:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd

x= pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=['a','b','c'])
mod = smf.ols(formula = 'a ~ b + c', data = x)
# worked just fine. data types are (non-nullable) int64's
```

But this doesn't:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd

x= pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=['a','b','c'])
x = x.convert_dtypes()
mod = smf.ols(formula = 'a ~ b + c', data = x)
# now an error: TypeError: Cannot interpret 'Int64Dtype()' as a data type
```

Is my inference correct? If so, is there a best (or at least slick) workaround?

statsmodels version: 0.12.2
pandas version: 1.1.5

Comment: You can open an issue on github as well. Moreover, if you are also working with data types other than integer, perhaps you could do this `x.convert_dtypes(convert_integer=False)` and check.

Comment: @Wave Yeah that works but actually I'm working with another dataframe where the types are imported (via pd. readcsv) automatically as Int64's. I suppose I'll just declare the data type(s) at that step. Thanks!

Comment: Ultimately this limitation binds from patsy, which is no longer being updated, and so does not know about newer types.